# Définition du mot ordinaire en Suisse

Tags: sens, usage, suisse

Bonjour,

J'ai remarqué qu'en Suisse le mot ordinaire est surreprésenté dans un contexte administratif par rapport à la France : Naturalisation ordinaire, professeur ordinaire, rente ordinaire, etc

Est-ce que ce mot a une signification différente? Sinon comment expliquer sa différence d'utilisation selon les pays?

Comment: « Surreprésenté » ne veut pas dire grand chose. Il faudrait donner des exemples de cas d'emplois dans le contexte Suisse et où vous pensez qu'en France on ne l'emploierait pas.

Comment: Cela dépend: professeur ordinaire: Phraseology
Les professeur-e-s ordinaires sont titulaires des postes principaux d'enseignement et de recherche. https://www.termdat.bk.admin.ch/Search/Search  Vous pouvez y faire des recherches. rente ordinaire n'est pas encore définie. Mais vous avez raison pour le mot ordinaire par rapport au language administratif et aux usages en France.

Answer (score 1):

Il y a certainement une différence de sens à l'origine de cette différence d'usage.

Le DHLF observe qu'au XVIe la langue familière s'empare d' *ordinaire* au sens de *normal, attendu* et surtout dans des formules négatives (*c'est pas ordinaire*), puis qu'au XVII l'adjectif prend le sens de *commun à un grand nombre de gens*.

De là, (toujours selon le DHLF) s'est développé un sens péjoratif de *commun, de niveau moyen, médiocre*. "*en parlant d'une personne, ordinaire exprime particulièrement une idée de condition sociale modeste*"

Je m'imagine qu'il devenait, dans ces conditions, difficile à conserver relativement à des titres administratifs.

Answer (score 1):

Une explication qui me semble plausible mais que je ne peux pas valider formellement est que le langage administratif en Suisse est le plus souvent traduit de l'allemand, ce qui a évidemment une influence sur le terme utilisé. En allemand, il est souvent utilisé le mot *[ordentlich](https://dict.leo.org/franz%C3%B6sisch-deutsch/ordentlich)* qui se traduit par *ordinaire* dans les textes adminitratifs et législatifs. Le terme en allemand n'a pas cette connotation négative que *ordinaire* a peut être en France.